# Facebook Login to app showing an error occured in oath dialog

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I was developing a app, friends whom you chat the most, so I wrote the following code to login to that application, but when I try to hit the login url, i get the following error message inside facebook oath permissions dialog page:
An error Occured, please try again.

The code I wrote is here:

```
<?php
require("facebook.php");
require("settings.php");
$facebook=new Facebook(array('app_Id'=>$app_id,'secret'=>$secret,'cookie'=>true));
$user=$facebook->getUser();
if($user)
{
    var_dump($user);
}
else
{
$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array("scope"=>"read_mailbox"));
    echo "<a href='$login_url'>Login</a>";
echo $login_url;
}
?>
```

the url to my testing app is: [www.cyberkiller.freeserver.me](http://www.cyberkiller.freeserver.me)
What may be the error in the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be appID not app_ID:

Incorrect:

```
$facebook=new Facebook(array('app_Id'=>$app_id,'secret'=>$secret,'cookie'=>true));
```

Correct:

```
$facebook=new Facebook(array('appId'=>$app_id,'secret'=>$secret,'cookie'=>true));
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the redirect given in your app and the redirect url given in your code, **IT SHOULD BE SAME**

It says the redirect url after loign

It will be given as **Site URL:** in your app edit page

Also check your app credentials

Use graph API it is simple.

Comment: ya, when i fixed the first error, it told:
An error occurred. Please try again later.

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.
Where do i have to give this redirect_uri? I cannot find the application configuration...

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=202358556569193&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcyberkiller.freeserver.me%2F&state=ae8df3f3abac374f7e62398a50a55ccc&scope=read_mailbox
this page says that app dont own the redirect url

Comment: ok, the problem is solved, the problem was on doing, http://www.mydomain.com and simply http://mydomain.com

Comment: i am sorry.. i was not here..:D